# C# Excel Sheets Processing Using Multiple Window Services for Inserting Data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, architecture

As Part of My Project, Client needs to upload Excel sheet (Multiple worksheets) . I am thinking in two way

1. We will upload Excel sheet on server location Then Multiple instance of window services will process Excel sheet data.

2.Second approach is That Instead of multiple instance of window services , I will use multiple tasks System.Threading.Tasks (as part of threading) and Process Excel sheet with one instance of window service

Any reference for technical design solution.

Comment: I would suggest option 3 three or something simular, where there is a single thread/process safe queue that queues work items for other services/threads to process.

With option 1 and 2 you might run into locks, I know with proper code that chance will be minimized but it might still happen, when reading files. Also it makes it more difficult to monitor if any progresss is made, where if there is a single queue it is easy to see if items are entering and/or leaving the queue.

MSMQ loses some performance if messages are persisted. But there are other queing systems.

Comment: If I will use 1st or 2nd Option Then What things I need to Take Care ?

Comment: What types of Excel sheets do you need to process ? Only xlsx or xls too ? There are various options for processing Excel files in C#, one of them is using interop with an installed Excel. But this is either not officially supported by Microsoft on a server, and problematic if used in the background. Please explain what you want to process (probably only reading data from the sheets and inserting in the DB )

Comment: Hello,I have multiple worksheet in excel like Product,Customer,Sizes,DeliveryDates.These all Sheets have data in tabular format in excel. Excel cells (header) is matching with database table column name.I need to read data from multiple worksheet in sequence as other worksheet data is dependent on first one. Like First I need to read produt sheet data and insert into database table and after that other sheet data.

Comment: I need to process xslx excel